# Boolean statement logic not correct

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
if (date.datetime.today().weekday == 5) or (date.datetime.today().weekday == 6):
     print('True')
```

What i am trying to do here is that the `if` statement should be true if today is saturday or sunday. 
The output is false even though today is Sunday. Why is this not True?

Comment: Try doing `print(datetime.datetime.today().weekday)` and you will find the reason. And the solution is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday)

Comment: You need to actually call the method like `if (date.datetime.today().weekday() == 5) or (date.datetime.today().weekday() == 6):`

Comment: There isn't a standard library `date` module. Did you mean `datetime.datetime`, or is this a third-party library? If for example you did `import datetime as date`, then the problem is that `weekday` here is a method and you haven't called it.

Comment: Please fix your code to make sense by adding your `import` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `weekday` must be followed by `()`, otherwise you are making a built in method object.

```
if (date.datetime.today().weekday() == 5) or (date.datetime.today().weekday() == 6):
     print('True')
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick working example, weekday is a method, you have to call it.

```
from datetime import date

if (date.today().weekday() == 5) or (date.today().weekday() == 6):
     print('True')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several problems:

- Your imports are likely wrong, and you didn't make it clear what you are using.
- `weekday` is a function, so you must call it, e.g. `weekday()`.
- You are calling today() twice, which means it could give you a race condition near midnight.

Therefore it should probably be:

```
import datetime
weekday = datetime.date.today().weekday()
# Or: weekday = datetime.datetime.today().weekday()
if ((weekday == 5) or (weekday == 6)):
    print("True")
```